# Android Bitmap.createBitmap returns negative mHeight

Tags: android, bitmap, width

Modifying the Snake example to another game, added a lot of stuff.  An exception was created from the bitmap class.  So I debug the original Snake which works fine, but found that in TileView there is a function loadTile giving negative width as well:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTileSize, mTileSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

after the above assignment, the bitmap had -1 for mHeight and mWidth.  Then how does the Snake even work?  I am just use the Eclipse and the virtual machine, not a real android phone.

Comment: Are you calling getWidth() and getHeight() to query the dimensions?  Or are you peaking at the class variables?

Comment: where is code related to mHeight, mwidth ?

Comment: After calling getWidth, found that the size were correct.  The exception was from the misuse of later code.  I will create another topic. Thanks!
mHeight value was known by just using Eclipse to debug.

Comment: This is apparently a feature, not a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808318/android-bitmap-createbitmap-returning-a-bitmap-with-1-for-height-and-width (Damn, I just spent almost an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong to produce this "erroneous" situation.)