# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns Bitmap with invalid dimensions?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to decode a jpeg buffer (by Camera.takePicture), using android.graphics.BitmapFactory. The android documentation states that `decodeByteArray` ["Returns the decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded."](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29)

No exception is thrown and I get a non-null object with invalid width and height:

```
android.graphics.Bitmap@41c7d960
[
mBuffer = ...
mFinalizer = android.graphics.Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer@41ca20c0
mWidth = -1
mHeight = -1
mDensity = 240
mLayoutBounds = null
mNativeBitmap = 1373749696
...
]
```

My function call is as follows:

```
public Func(byte [] jpegBuffer) {
        try {
            mBitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegBuffer, 0, jpegBuffer.length);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            mLog.e("Problem during jpeg decompression: " + e.toString());
        }   
    }
```

What is going on? Is the Bitmap decoded successfully or not? If yes, why are its dimensions invalid? If no, why am I not receiving a null result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808318/android-bitmap-createbitmap-returning-a-bitmap-with-1-for-height-and-width)

Basically, the fields `mWidth` and `mHeight` (as seen by the Eclipse debugger) re lazily-evaluated and inaccessible programatically, meaning they default to -1 until `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are called, respectively.

In conclusion, the android.Bitmap class may fool the debugging programmer by not updating some private fields that are visible to the debugger.